# Using chopper to add sums

Tags: java

My main program

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Lab13d
{
public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Will\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CompSci\\src\\compsci\\Lab13d.dat"));
        int num = file.nextInt();
        file.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            String line = file.nextLine();
            DogFood one = new DogFood(line);
            out.println(one);
       }
    }
}
```

And my second program that is linked to the first one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class DogFood
{
//Private instance variables
private double amount;
private String Line;
//Default constructor
public DogFood()
{
    amount = 0;
    Line = "";

}
//Initializer constructor
public DogFood(String line)
{
Line = line;
}
//Method to get the amount of dog food needed
    public double getAmount()
   {
        Scanner chopper = new Scanner(Line);
        double cups = 0.0;
        while(chopper.hasNextInt())
        { 
            if(chopper.nextInt() >= 2 && chopper.nextInt() <= 4)
            {
                cups += 3.5;         
            }
            else if(chopper.nextInt() >= 5 && chopper.nextInt() <= 7)
            {
                cups += 7.0;
            }
            else if(chopper.nextInt() >= 8 && chopper.nextInt() <= 9)
            {
                cups += 10.5;
            }
            else if(chopper.nextInt() >= 10 && chopper.nextInt() <= 19)
            {
                cups += 14.0;
            }
            else if(chopper.nextInt() >= 20 && chopper.nextInt() <= 39)
            {
                cups += 24.5;
            }
            else if(chopper.nextInt() >= 40 && chopper.nextInt() <= 59)
            {
                cups += 31.5;
            }
            else if(chopper.nextInt() >= 60 && chopper.nextInt() <= 79)
            {
                cups += 42.0;
            }
            else if(chopper.nextInt() >= 80)
            {
                cups += 52.5;
            }     
     } 
     return cups;
   }

    public String toString()
    {
        return getAmount() + " - 10 POUND BAGS";
    }
}
```

Lastly, here's my .dat file

```
8
4 6 8 10 12 14
2 2 3 4 5 6
5 10 15 20 25 30
5 20 35 40 55 60
6 10 14 18 25 32
12 15 20 26 35 42
33 38 45 51 60 65
40 50 60 77 90 101
```

Sorry for the poor formatting, I copied this from my IDE. What I'm trying to do is determine the weight at each int using chopper (starting after the first line of the .dat file, so on the 4 6 8 line). Which I believe I have down already, and then add a certain number to the amount of cups of dog food based on the weight. The error I'm getting is

```
run:
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
        at compsci.DogFood.getAmount(DogFood.java:48)
        at compsci.DogFood.toString(DogFood.java:74)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
        at compsci.Lab13d.main(Lab13d.java:26)
    C:\Users\Will\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Any help is much appreciated! I've been stuck on this for around 3 hours.

Comment: every time you call nextInt - new number is returned

Comment: Also, you don't want to call `getAmount()` in your `toString()` method. That would lead to have to keep parsing the `Line` every time you print the instance out. Call `getAmount()` once; store the value in a member variable; use that member variable in `toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `chopper.nextInt()` repeatedly in the conditional, assign it to a local variable:

```
int i = chopper.nextInt();
if (i >= 2 && i <= 4) {
  // ...
} else if (i >= 5 && i <= 7) {
  // ...
}
// etc.
```

Currently, your code is consuming an `int` from the stream every time it does a comparison. Eventually, it runs out of ints to read; it will throw an exception if there didn't happen to be a multiple of 15 ints available in the stream.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for so long. I really appreciate it!